# Trying to detect faces in mp4 (javacv + opencv) leads to fatal errors SIGSERV

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, kotlin, javacv

My best guess: Am I not releasing frames somehow?

I read a video using `org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber`, and convert the frames to `opencv_core.Mat`, then convert THOSE to `opencv.core.Mat` (because I need to run a `CascadeClassifier` on it and we can't have nice things).  I then skip frames that have already been processed.

Then it crashes.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010a6c2d21, pid=746, tid=0x0000000000005103
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_191-b12) (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.191-b12 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libopencv_java342.dylib+0xed21]  Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1delete+0x21
```

The odd thing is: if I don't skip the previously processed frames, it seems to work ok!  Which is why I was wondering if there was some race going on, where the time I take processing the frames gives the system time to catch up in clearing out garbage?

The code (should be able to check out project and run it in IntelliJ if you have a long enough input.mp4 file to test it on)

- [Kotlin sequence of Mat frames](https://github.com/salamanders/facesnap/blob/033a2ce839772f0edf0d6cbce508970c1afb82c7/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt#L20)
- [The line that seems to kill it (working with the Mat frame)](https://github.com/salamanders/facesnap/blob/033a2ce839772f0edf0d6cbce508970c1afb82c7/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt#L60)